# In Docker Swarm how does the services route when there's an update

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

If I do `docker stack deploy` I was wondering what the behaviour is as it's kind of hard to test on a single node system.

Say I have it set to `order: start-first` and say I have 10 replicas with `parallelism: 2`.  What I want is something like this.

1. So I would have 10 tasks running V1
2. I deploy the manifest so that the service should start using V2
3. It starts a two new V2 replicas
4. VIP still routes to the V1 replicas while it's still starting up
5. The following then occur when the the 2 V2 replicas have started:

   a. Two of the V1 replicas start a shutdown

   b. Two more V2 replicas have start
6. **Not sure about this one and I just want to confirm this** the VIP now routes new requests to the V2 replicas and stops routing new requests to the V1 replicas

The information does not seem to be documented in [update_config](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#update_config)

Comment: I don't know why docker would maintain a sham of keeping tasks around and healthy if it wasn't going to use them. If there are still 8 healthy v1 replicas, and 2 healthy v2 replicas, I see no reason the vip is not going to roundrobin across that whole set.